# Observer not firing - adminhtml_block_html_before

Tags: event-observer, adminhtml

I've been trying to develop a new module which will modify the admin html pages of a magento control panel but I'm having difficulty getting it to work. To debug I've rolled the module back to some really simple code to just write to the system.log file when the product edit page loads... and this still isnt working so I think I've got a problem with the observer actually firing. Can you see any problems?

app/etc/modules/tww_RemoveProductTabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <tww_RemoveProductTabs>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </tww_RemoveProductTabs>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/tww/RemoveProductTabs/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <tww_RemoveProductTabs>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </tww_RemoveProductTabs>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <tww_RemoveProductTabs>
                <class>tww_RemoveProductTabs_Model</class>
            </tww_RemoveProductTabs>
        </models>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <tww_RemoveProductTabs>
                        <class>tww_RemoveProductTabs/observer</class>
                        <method>removeTabs</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </tww_RemoveProductTabs>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/tww/RemoveProductTabs/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
    class tww_RemoveProductTabs_Model_Observer
    {
        public function removeTabs(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            Mage::log("Observer triggered");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: still not working?

Comment: Hi Adbul, I'm still having trouble getting this working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly close the `tww_RemoveProductTabs` node:

```
<tww_RemoveProductTabs>
    <class>tww_RemoveProductTabs/observer</class>
    <method>removeTabs</method>
    <type>singleton</type>
</tww_RemoveProductTabs>  // you have to properly close `tww_RemoveProductTabs`
```

Comment: Hi 7ochem, I have corrected this close but it is still not writing to the log - I've also updated by question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that logs are turned on? If so, turn on Developer Mode and check what happens.

Comment: The logs are definitely turned on. I've run through the use case with developer mode on and I cant see any difference. Any ideas? Thanks!